Enhancing my query for select information implement in oracle(plus/sql)
I'm working on my query for select information relate to the order table in oracle. I've written the following code. But I'm looking for suggest on how to improve it.
SELECT
    h.order_number,
    h.create_date,
    org.code AS branch_code,
    sc.code AS sale_chanel_code,
    emp.code AS sale_code,
    emp.fullname AS sale_name,
    dept.name AS department_name,
    tech.id AS tech_id,
    tech.name AS tech_name,
    d.PRINT_INVOICE_CHECK AS print_number,
    h.amount_discount,
    h.amount_voucher,
    paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
    h.amount_total,
    paya.cash_amount, 
    paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
    paya.card_amount,
    paya.cod_amount,
    h.order_status,
    c.id as cust_id,
    c.code as cust_code,
    c.name as cust_name
FROM
    tbl_order_header@posnew1_db h
    left JOIN tbl_order_detail@posnew1_db d ON h.id = d.order_header_id
    left JOIN tbl_item@posnew1_db it ON it.item_id = d.item_id
    left JOIN tbl_dm_customer@posnew1_db c ON c.id = h.cust_id
    left JOIN tbl_department@posnew1_db dept ON dept.department_id = h.dept_id
    left JOIN tbl_dm_master_org@posnew1_db org ON org.id = h.org_id
    left JOIN tbl_dm_sale_chanel@posnew1_db sc ON sc.id = h.sale_chanel_id
    left JOIN tbl_dm_technical_work@posnew1_db tech ON tech.id = h.technical_emp
    LEFT JOIN tbl_dm_employee@posnew1_db emp ON emp.id = h.sale_id
    left JOIN tbl_order_payment@posnew1_db payo ON h.id = payo.order_id
    left JOIN tbl_payment@posnew1_db pay ON pay.id = payo.payment_id
    left JOIN tbl_payment_method_apply@posnew1_db paya ON h.id = paya.order_id
GROUP BY
    h.order_number,
    h.create_date,
    org.code,
    sc.code,
    emp.code,
    emp.fullname,
    dept.name,
    tech.id,
    tech.name,
    d.PRINT_INVOICE_CHECK,
    c.id,
    c.code,
    c.name,
    h.amount_discount,
    h.amount_voucher,
    paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
    h.amount_total,
    paya.cash_amount, 
    paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
    paya.card_amount,
    paya.cod_amount,
    h.order_status
ORDER BY
    h.order_number ASC;

What improvements can make code this?

You haven't shown the definition of your tables and indexes, without which it's hard to give a good review.  I recommend you include these definitions (preferably as SQL statements, so that reviewers can reproduce your test environment).

This is a very simple query - what improvements are you looking for? Naming is a bit weird (why that ALL_CAPS for some column names?), but there's hardly a lot more to say. Simple SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... is really too trivial to review on its own.

primary keys
@TobySpeight:

recommend you include [table and index] definitions

You elected not to follow his excellent advice,
so it is hard to know what's unique and what isn't.
Having a good understanding of "this maps to that"
is usually an essential prerequisite for writing a query,
especially one that features a GROUP BY.
For example, "tech id maps to tech name".
Grouping by the following columns seems very very odd:
    h.amount_discount,
    h.amount_voucher,
    paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
    h.amount_total,
    paya.cash_amount, 
    paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
    paya.card_amount,
    paya.cod_amount,

They are dollar amounts, not
PK IDs.
It's not appropriate to uniquify on them.
And I see no aggregate functions in the query.
Please understand that result rows from a GROUP BY query
essentially have a new PK, dictated by the grouped columns.
That is, we could plausibly derive a brand new table from those rows.
But I can't imagine it would be sensible to do that with the OP query.
random case
    paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
    h.amount_total,
    paya.cash_amount, 
    paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
    paya.card_amount,
    paya.cod_amount,
    h.order_status,
    c.id as cust_id,

This would be a little easier to read if those two columns weren't SHOUTING
at me. Do upcase keywords such as AS, SELECT, FROM, and so on.
Writing a typo in uppercase makes it more obvious.
Please use conventional spelling for "amount".
unused JOIN table
    left JOIN tbl_item@posnew1_db it ON it.item_id = d.item_id

This appears to be leftover copy-n-paste material from another query.
Simply elide it.
The good news is your backend query planner will notice it is unused,
and ignore it.
The bad news is this makes it harder for colleagues to read your query.
odd prefix
Prepending tbl_ to each table name is silly.
Don't do it.
You wouldn't walk up to Alice and address her with "Hello,
person Alice, did you notice that person Bob is taking dog Spot for a walk?
I am eating some food franks and food beans right now.
Would you like some of my drink cola to drink?"
query plan

What improvements can make code this?

Hard to say, since you didn't include any EXPLAIN PLAN timing measurements.
Having more than ten tables participating in a JOIN query is a little worrying.
Hopefully each of those ON clauses is exploiting a unique index.
Examining the plan would let us verify that.
If your unspoken motivation for this Code Review submission
was, "my query is slow, how can I speed it up?", then consider
creating an intermediate reporting table,
or equivalently a MATERIALIZED VIEW. Things that change slowly,
such as customer and department identifiers, are good candidates for
denormalizing
in that way.
It's doing some of the JOIN work ahead of time, and caching the answer.
Then each interactive query you issue later can JOIN against cached results
and will have less work to do.

Even without table and index, there's 2 possible improvements to your request :
1- You JOIN tables you don't use
You don't use "it."(tbl_item), "payo."(tbl_order_payment) and "pay."(tbl_payment) anywhere in your request, and you group by every field in your select query (without using "group by function" like SUM() in the select)
2- Your GROUP BY should be unnecessary (or at least is way too big)
If you remove the useless JOINs and IF your tables don't have line duplicates (you shouldn't have any since you're using id everywhere, but you could have some data redundancy), since you're putting every field of your select in your group by, it mean that you are displaying every lines so in theory you don't need a GROUP BY at all :
SELECT
h.order_number,
h.create_date,
org.code AS branch_code,
sc.code AS sale_chanel_code,
emp.code AS sale_code,
emp.fullname AS sale_name,
dept.name AS department_name,
tech.id AS tech_id,
tech.name AS tech_name,
d.PRINT_INVOICE_CHECK AS print_number,
h.amount_discount,
h.amount_voucher,
paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
h.amount_total,
paya.cash_amount, 
paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
paya.card_amount,
paya.cod_amount,
h.order_status,
c.id as cust_id,
c.code as cust_code,
c.name as cust_name
FROM
tbl_order_header@posnew1_db h
left JOIN tbl_order_detail@posnew1_db d ON h.id = d.order_header_id
left JOIN tbl_dm_customer@posnew1_db c ON c.id = h.cust_id
left JOIN tbl_department@posnew1_db dept ON dept.department_id = h.dept_id
left JOIN tbl_dm_master_org@posnew1_db org ON org.id = h.org_id
left JOIN tbl_dm_sale_chanel@posnew1_db sc ON sc.id = h.sale_chanel_id
left JOIN tbl_dm_technical_work@posnew1_db tech ON tech.id = h.technical_emp
LEFT JOIN tbl_dm_employee@posnew1_db emp ON emp.id = h.sale_id
left JOIN tbl_payment_method_apply@posnew1_db paya ON h.id = paya.order_id
ORDER BY
h.order_number ASC;

If this query doesn't work as intended, at the very least the GROUP BY doesn't need more fields than that (keeping only the unique fields from each table when possible) :
GROUP BY
h.order_number,
org.code,
sc.code,
emp.code,
dept.name,
tech.id,
d.PRINT_INVOICE_CHECK,
c.id,
paya.POINT_EXCHANGE_AMOUT,
paya.cash_amount, 
paya.CUST_AMOUNT_TRANSFER,
paya.card_amount,
paya.cod_amount

And you should be able to remove most of those without issue.
